# Tasklist control in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Usually when I being a project at some place, the VS installation already includes the tasklist stuff.  In this new position the tasklist window does not show up under View/Other Windows.  How do I get the tasklist to work?  We are on a closed network and cannot connect to the internet with VS so that may add some difficulty.

Comment: Shortcut: ctrl + w,t

Comment: @Mark Thank you so much!! Perfect. Add an answer so I can give oyu credit!

Comment: posted, glad it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it via the Default Shortcut for the Task List

Shortcut: `ctrl + w,t`